# How to fix failing Open Directory (database "cn=authdata" cannot be opened, err 12) after hang

Tags: crash, open-directory

A Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5 server running Open Directory hung. SSH was still possible but the `sudo reboot` command didn't restart the server within 15 minutes. That is why a power cycle was issued. After the power cycle Open Directory would no longer start and the System log is filled with a new message every 10 seconds:

```
com.apple.launchd[1] (org.openldap.slapd[1153]): Exited with code: 1
com.apple.launchd[1] (org.openldap.slapd): Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
```

Repairing disk permission, neither another reboot doesn't solve the issue.

Slapd in Tool mode outputs:

```
$ sudo /usr/libexec/slapd -Tt
bdb(dc=nl2,dc=probackup,dc=nl): unable to allocate memory for mutex; resize mutex region
bdb_db_open: database "dc=nl2,dc=probackup,dc=nl" cannot be opened, err 12. Restore from backup!
backend_startup_one (type=bdb, suffix="dc=nl2,dc=probackup,dc=nl"): bi_db_open failed! (12)
slap_startup failed (test would succeed using the -u switch)
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Check if the OD database is the problem

```
$ sudo /usr/libexec/slapd -Tt
```

No further action is needed if the output tells something like:

```
...
bdb_db_open: database "dc=hostname,dc=domainname,dc=tldname": recovery skipped in read-only mode. Run manual recovery if errors are encountered.
...
```

## Try repair

To repair the Open Directory authdata database:

```
$ sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.openldap.slapd.plist
```

Now start the database recovery using the command below that matches your OS version.

```
$ sudo db_recover -h /var/db/openldap/authdata/ # Mac OS X 10.7
$ sudo db_recover -h /var/db/openldap/openldap-data/ # Mac OS X 10.6
```

Now slapd in tool mode outputs:

```
$ sudo /usr/libexec/slapd -Tt
bdb_db_open: database "dc=nl2,dc=probackup,dc=nl": unclean shutdown detected; attempting recovery.
bdb_db_open: database "dc=nl2,dc=probackup,dc=nl": recovery skipped in read-only mode. Run manual recovery if errors are encountered.
bdb_monitor_db_open: monitoring disabled; configure monitor database to enable
config file testing succeeded
```

Now turn back on Open Directory:

```
$ sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.openldap.slapd.plist
```

And issue another restart to be better safe than sorry:

```
$ sudo reboot
```

Open Directory should now be up and running again. In case it isn't running, try below.

## Try Time Machine restore

First have a look at the available back-upped versions:

```
$ ls /Volumes/Time\ Machine/Backups.backupdb/*/
```

Pick the most recent version when Open Directory was still running correctly, for example `2018-07-22-091106`.

Start again with unloading the daemon.

```
$ sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.openldap.slapd.plist
```

Then remove (or rename) the database directory (when it is available Time Machine won't restore correctly) and start restore:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /var/db/openldap/ && sudo tmutil restore -v /Volumes/Time\ Machine/Backups.backupdb/*/2018-07-22-091106/Macintosh\ HD/var/db/openldap/ /var/db/
```

Force repair the database:

```
$ sudo db_recover -cv -h /var/db/openldap/openldap-data/
```

Repair permissions and reboot:

```
$ sudo diskutil repairPermissions / && sudo reboot
```

Comment: This approach didn't exactly do the trick for me, but it set me on the right track. I don't really know what I'm doing with LDAP administration, so YMMV, but after running this command, I was able to restart slapd and my data hadn't been lost: `sudo db_recover -h /var/db/openldap/openldap-data/`. It seems like a different BDB database structure associated with LDAP had been corrupted in my particular case, so may be worth investigating if the above doesn't work for you. Good luck!

Comment: `/var/db/openldap/authdata` may also need to be recovered.

Answer (score 6):

This is how I usually repair a broken LDAP/OD

**1.** check if this is the problem

`sudo /usr/libexec/slapd -Tt`*

You might get: 
bdb_db_open: database "cn=authdata": db_open(/var/db/openldap/authdata/id2entry.bdb) failed: Invalid argument (22).

**2.** Stop LDAP on OD Master

`sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.openldap.slapd.plist`

**3.** Repair Permissions

`diskutil repairPermissions /`

**4.** backup openldap db

```
sudo cp /var/db/openldap/authdata/id2entry.bdb /var/db/openldap/authdata/id2entry.bdb.backup
```

**5.** repair

`sudo db_recover -cv -h /var/db/openldap/openldap-data/`

**6.** run repair again to check

`sudo db_recover -cv -h /var/db/openldap/openldap-data/`

**7.** do it one more time so things are repaired correctly

`sudo /usr/libexec/slapd -Tt`

**8.** restart the service

`sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.openldap.slapd.plist`

**9.** If the above does not work, try:

`sudo db_recover -cv -h /var/db/openldap/authdata/`

then I restart the service with step 8.

`sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.openldap.slapd.plist`

*This usually fixes the problem... but in some cases you need to restore like llange explaines in his post.*

Comment: In my situation, using catastrophic recovery was key. It makes sense to try the normal recovery mode first, but it helps to understand what -c provides.

Answer (score 1):

First best is to check the disk you may do so either using the recovery partition or single user (**cmd** - **S** at startup) then type :

```
fsck -fy
```

*QWERTY keyboard the dash is 2 key left from backspace.*

To re-import a corrupted database from a backup you should backup and replace the following files/ folders :

- **var/db/openldap/**
- **usr/bin/db_recover**

Not sure it's necessary but if you have removed the LDAPv3 entry in the System keychain :

- **Library/Keychains/System.keychain**

The try a recovery…

Then you should repair disk permissions from a terminal (not single user) :

```
diskutil repairPermissions /
```

If after the recovery you experience problem connecting to services check the configuration under "**Services**" tab in Directory Utility.

Answer (score 0):

Repair as proposed in the accepted answer was not able to fix my problems. However, **restoring the database from a Time Machine backup** was successful:

1. Unload OpenDirectory to be safe: `sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.openldap.slapd.plist`
2. Open a finder window, then select *Go > Go to folder* `/var/db`
3. Rename `/var/db/openldap` to something like `/var/db/openldap.corrupt`
4. Enter Time Machine
5. Go back in time to when you know OpenDirectory worked
6. Restore `/var/db/openldap`
7. Run a recover on the restored data:

```
sudo db_recover -cv -h /var/db/openldap/openldap-data/
sudo db_recover -cv -h /var/db/openldap/authdata/
```

9. Restart Open Directory: `sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.openldap.slapd.plist`

Once macOS Server has restarted, OpenDirectory should be up and running.